# There is no tab background attribute in the java code to change tab background dynamically

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-tabs, android-tablayout

How can i change the tab background dynamically by java code here is my layout code.if i can get the **app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_background"**  in the java code then i can able to change the background drawable by the position of the tab selection using selector to get the desired screen like the first image but i cant able to find it any where please help me out friends

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/icon_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/toolbar_bg"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_background"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/transparent"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="fixed" />


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

i need layout like below

[image]

But i am getting this layout

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You  need to create a listener for the `OnTabSelectedListener` event, and for each item init..`tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));`
and

```
tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorHeight((int) (2 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setCustomView(R.drawable.your_layout);   //2nd position
```

or you can also use custom layout view

```
tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setCustomView(R.layout.your_layout);
```

For overall `Tablayout`  use

```
tabLayout.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.your_drawable));
```

Comment: by creating custom layout how can i manage the UN-selected tab background

Comment: if u want to manage select unselect state u need a drawable selector...in question u are asking about particular position background `programetically`

Comment: Yup i am using the select to manage the select and unselect state and i need to change app:tab background programmatically sir